# C# Add Password to DataSet connection where ConnectionRef points to App.Config connection string

Tags: c#, dataset, connection-string

I have a DataSet.xsd file that has a TableAdapter with a MainSource DbSource. I want to override the connection string by adding a password in code (so as not to store the password in the App.Config file). The ConnectionRef points to a connection string in App.Config. How do I go about overriding that? I still want the base connection string stored in App.Config, but I want to replace the specific reference to add the password.

I found how to do it for the Entity framework, but I am not working with that, and even that response was rather unspecific as to where to put the code to override the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out how to override the behavior. And, every time I make an update, Visual Studio overwrites my code, but I figured out that I can modify the system generated code in the DataSet.Designer.cs file. It is not an ideal solution, but since I needed some solution, it was the best I could come up with. It answers my question for now. Perhaps when I figure out how to word my question better, I can ask another one that may generate more responses.